# Using javascript Open app in appstore/playstore if website is opened in mobile

Tags: javascript, android, ios, angularjs, mobile

I developed a website and a mobile app as my project. Now, if the website is opened in mobile browser, then i wish to open that app in mobile (if it is installed) otherwise open the app in the appstore. But don't open website in browser.

Using javascript I can know whether the website is being accessed by a mobile device or not. Please help me in redirecting to playstore/App.

Comment: I think what you are lloking for is Deep Link in android (https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html) an deeplinking in ios (http://blog.originate.com/blog/2014/04/22/deeplinking-in-ios/)

Comment: someone please help...